# "libaacdecoder.so" not found aacdecoder on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Using the aacdecoder  (https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/) I can play live audio on android version < 5.0. On Lolipop devices i'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.mobile.myplayer.debug-3/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.mobile.myplayer.debug-3/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libaacdecoder.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
```

How is it possible that "libaacdecoder.so" is not found only for Lilipop devices ?

Comment: Have you include the native libraries with your project? https://github.com/vbartacek/aacdecoder-android/tree/master/decoder/jni

Comment: no. I'm using aacdecoder as a mdoule in my project and the player module has jnilibs/armeabi/libaacdecoder.so

Comment: it seems to be because of multidexing that i'm using. If i remove it it works...

Answer (score 0):

move your `.so` files to folder `src/main/jniLibs`